# data processing workflow: aws lambda or ec2 instance?

Tags: image-processing, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm building an app, one aspect of it is the user can export images along with some csv files.

This usage of this function of the app would be intermittent. In other words there would be likely large amounts of time (months) between usage and then a period of time where it's hit pretty hard.

Currently I have this implemented using a python script that runs on an ec2 instance. The python script polls a sqs queue for json that contains the export details. The export json contains an array of images stored in s3, this array could contain between 1 and 5000 images, possibly more.

**The script basically does the following:**

- polls sqs for export message
- downloads s3 images
- resizes *(imagemagick)* /renames images based on data from export message
- groups images in directories based on data from export message
- creates csv files based on data from export message
- creates a .zip archive
- uploads .zip to s3

*Would this workflow be better for aws lambda considering the intermittency of use?*

*Can this workflow be done using lambda?*

*Would resizing 5k images be too time intensive for lambda?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major issues you will experience using an AWS Lambda function would be:

- Each function can run for a maximum of 5 minutes
- Each function only has 500MB of disk space
- Functions cannot be triggered by messages in an Amazon SQS queue (they should be triggered directly by the process that puts messages in the queue)

It is likely that your app would hit one of these limits. You could workaround the timing issue by chaining functions, but this is not recommended.

If you do not need to process such requests immediately, an **alternate design** could be:

- Create an **Auto Scaling group** that runs your application, with a minimum of zero instances and an appropriate maximum (that could even be just one instance)
- Configure **scaling policies** to scale-out when there are messages in the queue and scale-in when there are no messages in the queue
- Use **Spot Instances** to save money (just set the price to the On Demand price)

Comment: Spot instances are a great call, you COULD also consider SWF(https://aws.amazon.com/swf/), but given Sam has already got Python scripts running on servers - spot instances would be the one.